# How to copy .ts file compile result to output folder in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript

In visual studio, I can add .ts files to the project, and select typescript compile as the build action. Nice.

But the resulting .js file is not copied to build folder, regardless of the Copy to Output Directory option. Neither is the original ts file by the way.

How does one compile and copy the resulting file to the build folder?

Just for context, I need to read those files as text to send to a testing browser.

---

I have made it work by adding the js file to the project and setting copy to output on that file, but is there any guarantee that the ts file will be compiled before the js file is copied? I am down to checking every time, but there has to be a way.

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116305/generated-js-from-ts-in-visual-studio-2015), but it is mostly about why this happens than how to solve it, and there is no answer

Comment: Use a `tsconfig.json` and set `"outDir"`

Comment: I'd have to add both debug and release folders, is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer comes late but here is how you can do: open your project file and set the **output dir**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  [...]
  <TypeScriptOutDir>bin\$(Configuration)\</TypeScriptOutDir>
  [...]
</PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure the `PropertyGroup` doesn't have any condition ; for eg. `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Xyz'">`. If so, you can add another `PropertyGroup`